# asp.net web api angular CORS preflight issue with POST requests

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, cors

I have a webapi which is configured to use WINDOWS AUTHENTICATION.

```
var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute(origen, "*", "*") { SupportsCredentials = true };
            config.EnableCors(cors);
```

In my angular app I have the follwing methods:

GET methods work perfect.

```
result.CargarAreas = function (callBack, onError) {

        //url = WebApi + "Personas";
        var url = constants.apiPath + "Areas";

        //$http.get(url, { headers: { "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": constants.serverPath } })
        $http.get(url, {
            withCredentials: true
        })
        .then(function (data) {
            callBack(data);
        })
        .catch(function (data) {
            onError(data);
        });
    };
```

POST methods give me this error:

```
result.GuardarContacto = function (callBack, onError, data) {

        //url = WebApi + "Contactos";
        var url = constants.apiPath + "Contactos";

        $http.post(url, data, { headers: { "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": constants.serverPath } })

        .then(function (data) {
            callBack(data);
        })
        .catch(function (data) {
            onError(data);
        });
    };
```

and finally the web api method

```
[HttpGet]
        [Route("api/AutenticationSite")]
        public IHttpActionResult AutenticationSite()
        {
            string user = HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name.ToString();
            string[] subUser = user.Split('\\');
            bool respuesta = UsuariosDao.Authorize(subUser[1]);

            if (respuesta == true)
            {
                return Ok("Authenticated: " + user);
            }
            else
            {
                return BadRequest("Not authenticated" );
            }
        }
```

and the DAMN error we have been fighting for hours:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://a.b.com/api/Contactos. Response to
>   preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://a.b.com' is
>   therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401.

UPDATE 1

Info about the request and response

> Request URL:http://a.b.com/api/Contactos Request Method:OPTIONS Status
>   Code:200 OK Remote Address:181.143.YY.XX:80 Referrer
>   Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade Response Headers  (11) Request
>   Headers view source Accept:*/* Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
>   Accept-Language:es-ES,es;q=0.8
>   Access-Control-Request-Headers:content-type
>   Access-Control-Request-Method:POST Cache-Control:no-cache
>   Connection:keep-alive Host:a.b.com Origin:http://a.b.com
>   Pragma:no-cache Referer:http://a.b.com/Index.html
>   User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0

[image]

Comment: `$http.post(url, data, { headers: { "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"` are you setting `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` in the request header? that's not how CORS access is granted - the server must respond with a `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` ... setting such a header in the request will trigger a pre-flight OPTIONS request, which needs to be handled by the server correctly for CORS to work ... notice how GET works, because you aren't sending a "non-standard" header in the request

Comment: I just removed it and still get the same problem

Comment: check the request in the developer tools network tab - look the request headers, response headers, request type (is it still preflighting an OPTIONS request)

Comment: @LuisValencia-MVP check what you got for `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` Header in developer tools -> network tab  -> headers. I think you may need `[EnableCors]` attribute on right above on your function

Comment: mmm, weird, it says request method options

Comment: I just pasted the request and response headers, any lights on it?

Comment: It does not return `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` in response, But it should. Have you gone through this? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api

Comment: I just added a picture with the request and response details

Comment: Options request seems to be returning 200 OK. So the actual error code be in subsequent request i.e. actual request. Options preflight request is a way of browser/client to determine if its allowed subsequent request and that is working fine. Can you spot error in your OnError function, if it contains something useful. Also, is there any extra code for enabling Cors in web.config file? If yes, remove that.

Comment: Also, could you please share the response of actual request (i.e. POST) sent after receiving response fr preflight options request?

Comment: how can I write the error? hovering the error variable doesnt show anything

Comment: @LuisValencia were you able to fix this? Although your query was an year back, but if fixed, please post your solution which helped you

Comment: I was having the same issue, what i found was i needed to add host entry (ip and url)

Answer (score 0):

Remove access-control header setting in your angular code. 
Looks like you have this header getting set at multiple places and thus the output is having none, despite your web api code enabling cors.

Look out for

- web.config => httpRuntime => httpHandlers => header getting set
- Usage of MVC.CORS NuGet 'instead' of WebAPI.CORS package. Here your need to use the WebAPI one (although it depends on MVC one so don't uninstall it)
- No need to change the OPTIONS verb handler in global.asax
- Multiple calls to *config.EnableCors* in different places (global.asax and webapi.config). Search across your source for 'cors' just to be sure on this.
- Check if the attribute is set on a global level or controller/action level. It may be that your specific action is getting excluded. Try doing a post on some other controller to be sure
- Variable 'origen' correctly stores the client's IP address and port. Any deviation will lead to not sending header. Try using star * rather than specific client to test.